# What do I do when i receive this feedback after running a code in C?

Tags: c, powershell, visual-studio-code

Feedback after running code in vscode;

```
gcc : The term 'gcc' is not recognized as the name 
of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct 
and try again.
At line:1 char:40
```

The code I input;

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main()  {
   printf("Hello World")
}
```

Comment: What OS? What version of gcc do you have installed?

Comment: Also judging by the flood of beginner questions we get on SO regarding Visual Studio Code, it is apparently completely unsuitable for beginners. Get a better IDE which comes with compiler, linker and debugger preinstalled.

Comment: "after running code":  no, you didn't run anything. gcc is the name of a compiler that vscode  tries to find but fails due to an incomplete configuration of the tools.

Comment: The error message is the message printed by Windows PowerShell when an unknown command is entered. It's likely to be Windows. But this should still be mentioned in the question.

Comment: When you run a C program in vsCode, you get the errormessage from Windows Powershell that a UNIX/Linux compiler is not found. I'm afraid your configuration is severely messed up.

Comment: @Dominique What are you even talking about? gcc for Windows is a thing since some 30+ years back. How can you tell that the OP is using Windows? Also there are other OS besides Linux and Windows.

Comment: Reminder for OP: You are supposed to monitor comments for your question and respond to feedbach, e.g. clarify what OS you are using.

Comment: @Ludin I'm using windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to install the gcc compiler on your system and it add to path. here u can take help.

https://www.scaler.com/topics/c/c-compiler-for-windows/

Comment: Nothing in the question indicates that this is for Windows, so the question can't be answered without that clarification.

Comment: @Lundin The question has the [powershell] tag

Comment: @JeremyP Because someone just added that tag out of the blue. No idea why, looks like an incorrect edit.

Comment: @Engr.Aftab Ufaq I have been able to resolve the problem with the link you attached https://www.scaler.com/topics/c/c-compiler-for-windows/ . Thank you.